# How to update Ubuntu 19.04 to the latest version using the terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, repository

I have tried using `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`. But it is not working.

```
Hit:1 http://linux.*********r.com/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:5 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease            *******
Ign:6 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:7 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease****
Hit:8 https://repo.*****.com/deb stable InRelease
Ign:9 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Hit:10 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports InRelease
Ign:11 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Hit:12 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease
Ign:13 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Err:14 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  404  Not Found [IP: ****************]
Err:15 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
  404  Not Found [IP: ****************]
Err:16 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
  404  Not Found [IP: ****************]
Err:17 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
  404  Not Found [IP: ****************]
Get:3 https://mirrors.bfsu.edu.cn/****/systems/win32/******/setup/deb bionic InRelease [2,034 B]
Err:3 https://mirrors.bfsu.edu.cn/****/systems/win32/******/setup/deb bionic InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 277A7293F59E4889 ****** Packager <packager@******.org>
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by defualt.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by defualt.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by defualt.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by defualt.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: https://mirrors.bfsu.edu.cn/****/systems/win32/******/setup/deb bionic InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 277A7293F59E4889 MiKTeX Packager <packager@******.org>
E: The repository 'http://**********/download/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by defualt.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

> Unable to download updates:
>
> failed to refresh cache: E: The repository
> 'http:old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a
> Release file.

The Software Updater also provides an error:

> **Failed to download repository information**
>
> Check your connection.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site. Unfortunately "it is not working" is far too unspecific. Please edit your question to include _how_ it is not working, e.g. by providing error messages you receive.

Comment: What happens when you `sudo apt autoremove` then `sudo apt dist-upgrade`?

Comment: The problem is still the same  - "Failed to download repository information"

and

"failed to refresh cache:E: The repository ......."

Comment: You cannot update it as it is EoL - end of life. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases You can upgrade it to 20.04.1, but some auto upgrades are held as some issue on upgrade. I believe more in good backups & new install. https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2020/08/ubuntu-20-04-upgrade-notification-delay

Comment: @oldfred It seems that your comment is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

run this command

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d -f DistUpgradeViewGtk3
```

Then start the upgrade.

Comment: "Checking for a new Ubuntu release
There is no development version of an LTS available.
To upgrade to the latest non-LTS development release 
set Prompt=normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades."



This is the output. But after that, I used 'sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade'. But it failed again to update.